# $\angle AOB=75°$, $\angle CBD=62°$, $\angle BAD=30°$ find $\angle BDA$ and $\angle ABD$

Tags: geometry

I was looking at some geometry examples and struggling to solve this one:

Given that $O$ is the center of the circle and that $\angle AOB=75°$, $\angle CBD=62°$, and $\angle BAD=30°$ calculate:

a) $\angle BDA$

b) $\angle ABD$

**So  far I have found $\angle ACB=37.5°$**

[image]

Can you please help?

Comment: You should edit your question and include what you have tried so far on the problem.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout I have just done it

Comment: How do you know that points are on the circle?

Comment: You can find $\angle BDA$ the same way you found $\angle ACB$.

Comment: @cansomeonehelpmeout
∠AOB=75° also equal to 2x alfa, then ∠ACB= to alfa which is 37.5° . Is it right to assume that ∠BDA is the same as ∠ACB? This is based on using peripheral angle and central angle

Comment: Yes, that sounds right. Both inscribed angles shares the same central angle.

Comment: Yes, you are right thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Note the

a) $\angle BDA=\frac{1}{2}\overparen{AB}=\frac{1}{2}\angle AOB=37,5º$

and

b) $\angle ABD=\frac12\overparen{ACD}=\frac12(360º-\overparen{AB}-\overparen{BD})=\frac12(360º-\angle AOB-2.\angle BAD)=112,5º$.

For details of this properties see https://mathbitsnotebook.com/Geometry/Circles/CRAngles.html

Answer (score 0):

For the second part note that $$180^\circ=\angle ABD+\angle BDA+\angle BAD$$ and you have already found $\angle BDA$, and it is given that $\angle BAD=30^\circ$.